# Xen 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 not booting

Tags: ubuntu, xen, grub2

I'm trying to get Xen 4.0.1 run as dom0 on a fresh/clean install of 10.10 desktop (x64).

Followed the step by step tutorial at http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/Xen4.0

I have the pvops kernel in /boot, also included the ext4 fs support by recompiling the kernel by :

```
make -j6 linux-2.6-pvops-config CONFIGMODE=menuconfig
make -j6 linux-2.6-pvops-build
make -j6 linux-2.6-pvops-install
```

Here's my grub entry :

```
menuentry 'Xen4' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        insmod ext3
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 2bf3177a-92fd-4196-901a-da8d810b04b4
        multiboot  /xen-4.0.gz dom0_mem=1024M loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all
        module     /vmlinuz-2.6.32.27 root=UUID=2bf3177a-92fd-4196-901a-da8d810b04b4 ro
        module     /initrd.img-2.6.32.27
}
```

blkid /dev/sda1 gives the :

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="2bf3177a-92fd-4196-901a-da8d810b04b4" TYPE="ext3"
```

My partition shemes is :

```
/boot (ext3)
/ (ext4)
```

Whatever option i've tried i end up with :

```
mounting none on /dev failed: no such file or directory
```

And message complaining that it cannot find the device with uuid ...

It's taking my hairs out, if somone has a clue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have ramdisk for your kernel ? 
I've ran through these srcipts yesterday under Ubuntu 10.10 and had to create ramdisk manually though, then my server booted just fine ...
And more importantly : are there all modules for filesystems and sata and raid controllers in kernel/ramdisk ? (You have to check for them - xen builder won't add them automatically)

`update-initramfs -c -k 2.6.32.27`

Comment: Yes i did. Finally solved by adding : +KERNEL=="gntdev", NAME="xen/%k"
+KERNELS=="xen", KERNEL=="xvd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", OPTIONS+="last_rule" to /tools/hotplug/Linux/xen-backend.rule. Simple and stupid as that.